# Is it possible to match all the fields in one table with other through third table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering whether this problem can be solved in one query:

There are three tables:
`users (id, name, is_online)`
`groups (id, name)`
`user_groups (user_id, group_id)`

And as a result, I need to get a combination of users who have '1' in `is_online` field and all the groups with some mark - whether the user belongs to a group or not.

For example, if there were only three groups in the `groups` table, the result would be like this:

```
 | user_id | group_id | in_group |
 | 100     | 1        | 1        |
 | 100     | 2        | 0        |
 | 100     | 3        | 0        |
 | 101     | 1        | 0        |
 | 101     | 2        | 0        |
 | 101     | 3        | 0        |
 | 102     | 1        | 1        |
 | 102     | 2        | 1        |
 | 102     | 3        | 1        |
```

I was thinking about using some mechanism like full join, but still couldn't come up with a certain idea how to properly combine users and groups through that third table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `CROSS JOIN` users with groups so as to get a list of all possible combinations between the records of the two tables. Then `LEFT JOIN` `user_groups` table to see if there is match or not for each of the combinations:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, IF(ug.user_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)
FROM users AS u
CROSS JOIN groups AS g
LEFT JOIN user_groups AS ug ON u.id = ug.user_id AND g.id = ug.group_id
WHERE u.is_online = 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2db10d/4)